# Stuck Allen bolt in e3d hotend

Tags: 3d-printing

I was having bed leveling issues, so I wanted to make sure I had my x axis level. I moved the z axis right to the top so it would align itself. But in the process, I must have ripped the cable clean off the heater cartridge.

Anyway, now I have no way to get it hot and the screw that clamps the heater block around the cartridge won't move. Why do they get stuck like that? I don't think I over tightened it. I used a screwdriver bit set not an allen key, so I don't think I had so much leverage that I over tightened it.

Comment: Can you heat it up with a soldering iron? (use a solder blob to create good thermal transfer)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a hot air tool you can use it instead. I set it to 450 and 100 air speed. It took around a minute  or so to get it hot enough. A soldering iron may work but it'll be slower. I haven't tried a heat gun but I would imagine it'll work.